# Laravel Collection - Return Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, rest, collections

So I am trying to return an array of objects with my Laravel collection using the following code:

```
/**
 * View a user's chat rooms.
 *
 * return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory\
 */
public function viewChatRooms()
{
    $user = Auth::user(); // @var User $user
    $username = $user->username;

    $rooms = Room::with('messages')->get()
                    ->filter(function ($val) use ($username){
                        foreach ($val->users as $user) {
                            if($user === $username){
                                return $val;
                            }
                        }
    });

    return response(['rooms' => $rooms]);
}
```

Instead of returning an array of objects, the response returns the following:

```
{
    "rooms": {
        "0": {...},
        "3": {...}
    }
}
```

This is the desired result:

```
{
    "rooms": [
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Kind of stumped by this, could some one guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You Can use array_value function of PHP when returning response like this:**

```
return response()->json([
    'rooms' => array_values($rooms->toArray())
]);
```

**Laravel Collection Methods for Getting only values of Collection**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-values

So

```
return response()->json([
    'rooms' => $rooms->values()->toArray()
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, the second answer work perfectly. I would've used `whereHas` but there is no direct user relation as the database stores the usernames in a json format, thus not allowing me to use the last answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I didn't rebase the array since it skipped a few keys. I fixed it by simply using `array_values()` like so:

```
$rooms = Room::with('messages')->get()
                ->filter(function ($val) use ($username){
                    foreach ($val->users as $user) {
                        if($user === $username){
                            return $val;
                        }
                    }
        });

return response(['rooms' => array_values($rooms->toArray())]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will find that doing this within your DB query will be better performance wise.

Something like this:

```
$rooms = Room::whereHas('users', function(user) use ($username) {
        return $user == $username
    })
    ->with('messages')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To return an array of objects, you can use the [all](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-all) method.

Instead of returning a collection of objects, it returns an array of objects.

For example, `User::all();` returns an Eloquent collection which is structured like so:

```
[
    {App\User},
    {App\User},
    {App\User}
]
```

Whereas, the other answers suggest using `->toArray()` which returns an array of **arrays**, not an array of *objects*, e.g.:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 123,
        'name' => 'example'
        ...
    ],
    [
        ...
    ]
]
```